# infinite scroll in Ionic not working

Tags: scroll, infinite

I am trying to implement infinite scroll however, it is not working. it keeps loading the same number of pages and doesn't load new pages. Id appreciate any help.

this is my controller :

```
$scope.getsomeinfo = function () {
            $scope.isLoading = true;
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Loading ..'
            });

            info.getsomeinfo()
                .then($scope.someinfo
                , $scope.fjbfuirbf);
        };


        $scope. = function () {
            var options = {};
             = );





        };
```

Comment: Joanna, is there a reason that you keep suggesting vandalizing edits to the answers on this question?  If you feel the answer is incorrect, editing it into gibberish is NOT the way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your code

this line

```
options.page = Math.ceil($scope.allDeals.count + 10 / 10);
```

should be

```
options.page = Math.ceil(($scope.allDeals.count + 10)/ 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the attributes in defaultParams are correct (in the second call), so something like:

```
var defaultParams = {
           mobileready: 1,
           company_id: COMPANY_ID,
           count: 10,
           page: 2
    };
```

could be a webservice problem?

Are you sure that  /someinfo/info work as you intended?